# Laravel Migrations XML Datatype

Tags: php, database, laravel, postgresql

exists the data type XML on Laravel Migrations for PostgreSQL?

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html

Thank You.
Kind Regards

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The available column types are [documented here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#creating-columns). XML is not among them - Laravel's Schema Builder typically only supports widely-shared column types, or ones where the functionality can be largely simulated (like SQLite using `TEXT` to store a `JSON` column).

It's certainly possible to do it via a raw query to the database, using something like `DB::statement`. Doing so will tie you to Postgres a bit, though.

You could also store it as a `TEXT` field and have [accessor/mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators) handle the validation that it's valid XML before insertion.